# Spring security with Google OAuth and generate custom token

Tags: spring-security, google-oauth, access-token

I have implemented spring security for **UsernamePassword** based authentication. 
Tables like **oauth_access_token, oauth_client_details** etc are created by spring. 
Tokens generated by `tokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(principal, parameters);` are stored in oauth_access_token table.

Scenario:

I need to have both usernamPassword based authentication and Google OAuth support.

Now I have to integrate Google OAuth in my application.
I can't use Google's API for every request validation so once I get the user profile from Google I'm trying to generate the token using `tokenEndPoint` and give it to client (Mobile App/Front end).

Problem:

-> I can't use "password" as grant type, as there is no password in this case and if I use password as grant type then Spring security uses password in DB for password validation

Is my approach correct.? what should I do here to store tokens in **oauth_access_token** table?

What is the best practice to support Social login and generate custom token which will be shared with the client.?